# Twitter search api arabic query

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, twitter, encoding

App Correctly authorized, after making this request to Twitter API server:

```
class test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    client = main.get_client()
    query = u'يوم_الجمعه'
    args = {'q':query.encode('utf-8'),'lang':'ar','resut_type':'popular'}
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?'+urllib.urlencode(args)
    resp, content = client.request(url)
    self.response.write(content)
```

I get :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        v = quote_plus(str(v))
>        UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the [ouath1-python](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2) fixed the problem of non ascii charchter encoding.